# how to concatenate multiple unstructured iterables into one 2d numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy

What is the easiest way to concatenate something like this:

```
arr = [
       [1,2,3,4,5],  # len 5, not iterable inside
       [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5, 6)],  # len 5
       np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5],[4,5,6,],[5,6,7]])  # len 5]
```

into this

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], chained all first elements from all 3 arrays
       [2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], chained all second elements from all 3 arrays
       [3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5], ...
       [4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6], ...
       [5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]])
```

Tried `numpy.stack` and `numpy.concatenate`, but get problems with different dimensions inside initial arrays (because of first array with only integers)

Comment: So you have a (5,), (5,2) and (5,3).  Make the first a (5,1), then they can all be joined on axis 1, to create a (5,6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html). It stacks inner arrays as columns and automatically converts the shape for you if necessary:

```
np.column_stack(arr)
array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6],
       [5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7]])
```

Comment: While `column_stack` does the job for you, it's a good idea to learn how to add a dimension to that (5,) shape.  Understanding shapes and reshaping is a fundamental `numpy` skill.